# Coloring the cluster with same colors as defined for ground truth for visualization

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

Example: (Consider the platform = MATLAB)

```
Ground_Truth_Indices = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
```

For each unique index in the GT, I have defined a color array.

```
Color_Array = [ 0, 255, 0;  255, 0, 0;  0, 0, 255]; %assuming (in this eg.) the max. cluster size is 3
```

Next, I use a clustering algorithm (DBSCAN in my case) and it gives the following indices:

```
Clustered_Indices = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1];
```

Now, I need to visualize the results alongside the ground truth. 
But the obtained indices, after clustering, are different from the ground truth indices.

**Thus, according to the color array defined, I would not get the same pattern of colors for ground truth and obtained clusters during visualization. Is there any solution so that I could make both the colorings consistent?**

[Figure with ground truth and obtained clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uupa1.png)

The same is illustrated in the above link to the figure (not a MatLab plot! Created for the purpose of illustration), where the Cluster 1 should have the same color in the ground truth as well as the obtained cluster results. But, it is not the case here because of the index number associated with colour array defined.

Note: The indices obtained after the clustering cant be predefined and depends on the clustering algorithm and clustering input.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your post and add some figures showing what clustering you expect to get and what you _are_ getting? As a side note, comments in MATLAB start with `%` and not `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kuhn-Munkres maximum matching ([Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)) to find the best  1:1 alignment of the cluster labels.

As the generated clustering may have a different number of clusters, you'll need a robust implementation that can find alignments in non-square matrixes.

Butyou may be more interested in visualizing the differences between the clusterings. I've seen this in the following paper, but I am not sure if this is usable beyond toy data sets:

> Evaluation of Clusterings -- Metrics and Visual Support
>   Elke Achtert, Sascha Goldhofer, +2 authors Arthur Zimek
>   Published in IEEE 28th International… 2012
>   DOI:10.1109/ICDE.2012.128

(Sorry for the incomplete reference, blame semantic scholar, but that was easiest to link a figure from the paper, I can't take a better screenshot on this device).

This seems to visualize the differences between a k-means and an EM clustering, where grey points are those where they agree on the clustering. This approach seems to work on pairs of points, just as the evaluation measures.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the answer to this post:
[How can I match up cluster labels to my 'ground truth' labels in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683785/how-can-i-match-up-cluster-labels-to-my-ground-truth-labels-in-matlab?rq=1), I have the following solution code for my question:

```
N = length(Ground_Truth_Indices);

cluster_names = unique(Clustered_Indices);
accuracy = 0;
maxInd = 1;

perm = perms(unique(Ground_Truth_Indices));
[perm_nrows perm_ncols] = size(perm);

true_labels = Ground_Truth_Indices;

for i=1:perm_nrows
    flipped_labels = zeros(1,N);
    for cl = 1 : perm_ncol
        flipped_labels(Clustered_Indices==cluster_names(cl)) = perm(i,cl);
    end

    testAcc = sum(flipped_labels == Ground_Truth_Indices')/N;
    if testAcc > accuracy
        accuracy = testAcc;
        maxInd = i;
        true_labels = flipped_labels;
    end

end
```

where 'true_labels' contains the re-arranged labels for the variable 'Clustered_Indices' in accordance with the variable 'Ground_Truth_Indices'.

> This code as explained in the original post uses permutation-based
>   matching (It works well for the example which I had given in this post. I also tested with other variations). But, when the size of the cluster becomes large this code
>   does not work well. What do think about this code? Is there a better
>   way to write it? Or optimize it?